# Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).onclick is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I am running this code to try to let users select the size of a table / matrix. Users can click in a table to select the size of the matrix. However, I'm getting an error for when I try to access `onclick` of one of the `<td>` elements.

Specifically, I get the following error on line 179: `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).onclick` is not a function.

I've looked up this error on previous stackoverflow questions, and it seems what people did in the past was redeclare the function (in my case, `onclick`) to be a different function / variable. In this document, the only instance of `onclick` where the error is being thrown.

You can view a live version of this webpage [here](http://la.matthewpagecs.com/LinearAlgebraCalculator/index.html), and the source is below.

Edit: Ok, I guess linking directly to my page makes it crash for some reason. Try copying and pasting the URL instead: http://la.matthewpagecs.com/LinearAlgebraCalculator/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Linear Algebra Calculator</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #111111;
            color: #DDDDDD;
        }
        td {
            background-color: #444444;
            padding: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Linear Algebra Calculator</h1>
    <p>Click on one of the cells in the table below to select your matrix size.</p>
    <div id="table">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(0, 0)" id="0,0"></td>    
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(0, 1)" id="0,1"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(0, 2)" id="0,2"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(0, 3)" id="0,3"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(0, 4)" id="0,4"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(0, 5)" id="0,5"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(0, 6)" id="0,6"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(0, 7)" id="0,7"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(0, 8)" id="0,8"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(0, 9)" id="0,9"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(1, 0)" id="1,0"></td>    
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(1, 1)" id="1,1"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(1, 2)" id="1,2"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(1, 3)" id="1,3"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(1, 4)" id="1,4"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(1, 5)" id="1,5"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(1, 6)" id="1,6"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(1, 7)" id="1,7"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(1, 8)" id="1,8"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(1, 9)" id="1,9"></td>
        </tr>   

        <tr>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(2, 0)" id="2,0"></td>    
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(2, 1)" id="2,1"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(2, 2)" id="2,2"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(2, 3)" id="2,3"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(2, 4)" id="2,4"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(2, 5)" id="2,5"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(2, 6)" id="2,6"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(2, 7)" id="2,7"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(2, 8)" id="2,8"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(2, 9)" id="2,9"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(3, 0)" id="3,0"></td>    
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(3, 1)" id="3,1"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(3, 2)" id="3,2"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(3, 3)" id="3,3"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(3, 4)" id="3,4"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(3, 5)" id="3,5"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(3, 6)" id="3,6"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(3, 7)" id="3,7"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(3, 8)" id="3,8"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(3, 9)" id="3,9"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(4, 0)" id="4,0"></td>    
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(4, 1)" id="4,1"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(4, 2)" id="4,2"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(4, 3)" id="4,3"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(4, 4)" id="4,4"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(4, 5)" id="4,5"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(4, 6)" id="4,6"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(4, 7)" id="4,7"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(4, 8)" id="4,8"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(4, 9)" id="4,9"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(5, 0)" id="5,0"></td>    
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(5, 1)" id="5,1"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(5, 2)" id="5,2"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(5, 3)" id="5,3"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(5, 4)" id="5,4"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(5, 5)" id="5,5"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(5, 6)" id="5,6"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(5, 7)" id="5,7"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(5, 8)" id="5,8"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(5, 9)" id="5,9"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(6, 0)" id="6,0"></td>    
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(6, 1)" id="6,1"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(6, 2)" id="6,2"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(6, 3)" id="6,3"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(6, 4)" id="6,4"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(6, 5)" id="6,5"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(6, 6)" id="6,6"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(6, 7)" id="6,7"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(6, 8)" id="6,8"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(6, 9)" id="6,9"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(7, 0)" id="7,0"></td>    
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(7, 1)" id="7,1"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(7, 2)" id="7,2"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(7, 3)" id="7,3"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(7, 4)" id="7,4"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(7, 5)" id="7,5"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(7, 6)" id="7,6"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(7, 7)" id="7,7"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(7, 8)" id="7,8"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(7, 9)" id="7,9"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(8, 0)" id="8,0"></td>    
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(8, 1)" id="8,1"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(8, 2)" id="8,2"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(8, 3)" id="8,3"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(8, 4)" id="8,4"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(8, 5)" id="8,5"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(8, 6)" id="8,6"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(8, 7)" id="8,7"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(8, 8)" id="8,8"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(8, 9)" id="8,9"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(9, 0)" id="9,0"></td>    
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(9, 1)" id="9,1"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(9, 2)" id="9,2"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(9, 3)" id="9,3"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(9, 4)" id="9,4"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(9, 5)" id="9,5"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(9, 6)" id="9,6"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(9, 7)" id="9,7"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(9, 8)" id="9,8"></td>
            <td onmouseenter="newSelection(9, 9)" id="9,9"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <h1 id="selection"></h1>
    <script>
        function newSelection(row, column) {
            clearSelection();
            for (i = 0; i <= row; i++)
                for (j = 0; j <= column; j++)
                    document.getElementById(i + "," + j).style.backgroundColor = "#CCCCCC";
            row++;
            column++;
            document.getElementById("selection").innerHTML = row + " x " + column + " matrix";
        }

        function clearSelection() {
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    document.getElementById(i + "," + j).style.backgroundColor = "#444444";
        }

        function ceck() {
            document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = "You selected an element.";
        }

        // add onclick listeners
        window.onload = function() {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                document.getElementById(i + "," + j).onclick(ceck)
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) is indeed not a function but property. You should assign a function to it to handle event. So it should be:

```
document.getElementById(i + "," + j).onclick = ceck;
```

Comment: Ok, that helped! But now whenever the web page is loaded, it automatically clicks the second cell loaded, without me even moving the mouse into the web page. Is this just something I need to account for? Or is there a way to stop ceck from being called when the page loads?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://plnkr.co/edit/02wm1Qn6syMxM2zQOrcl?p=preview I guess you have something else on the page.

Comment: when you assign a function to onclick, it needs to be an anonymous function, or a function that returns a function, or else it will run on assignment: `document.getElementById(i + "," + j).onclick = function() {ceck();};`

Answer (score 3):

[MDN - onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) is a property.

> The onclick property returns the click event handler code on the current element.

```
document.getElementById(i + "," + j).onclick = ceck;
```

Or you can use an anonymous function, like this:

```
document.getElementById(i + "," + j).onclick = function() { alert("Hello"); };
```